# Gitlab Self Hosted Runners Standby

Tags: gitlab

I am running Gitlab Self Hosted version 15.0. Is there a way to have a certain number of pods/runners on standby for new jobs at all times?

Comment: What do you mean, exactly? The more details you can provide about your current situation and your expectations the better. What type of runner executor are you using? Do you mean you want to avoid waiting for image pulls / service startup? Or something else?

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use a "[Docker Machine Executor autoscale configuration](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/autoscale.html)":

> GitLab Runner can autoscale, so that your infrastructure contains only as many build instances as are necessary at any time.
>
> If you configure GitLab Runner to only use autoscale, the system on which GitLab Runner is installed acts as a bastion for all the machines it creates.  This machine is referred to as a "**Runner Manager**".

It includes:

> **`IdleCountMin`**. It defines the minimum number of Idle machines that need to be sustained no matter what `IdleScaleFactor` will evaluate to.
> The setting can’t be set to less than 1 if `IdleScaleFactor` is used. If done so, Runner will automatically set it to 1.
>
> You can also use `IdleCountMin` to **define the minimum number of Idle machines that should always be available**.
> This allows new jobs entering the queue to start quickly.